# How do I get rid of annoying code tips in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, optimization, tooltip, coderush

When I first open Visual Studio 2010, I accidentally said "Yes" to help/code tips or something. Now whenever I type code, I get these annoying pop-ups explaining what happened or trying to improve my code, etc. These help tips are making it difficult to code and causing Visual Studio to run slowly.

**How do I disable them?**

[image: Example of one of the annoying code tips]

[image: Another example of one of the annoying code tips]

Edit: my apologies for posting this. I did not realize it was off-topic. Does Stack Overflow have a proper place for questions about software tools such as IDEs?

Comment: @Macmade, how is a question about Visual Studio configuration off-topic?

Comment: @Brandon Would be better on SuperUser IMHO...

Comment: i.e For C/C++ `Quick Info`, you'd set `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced->Auto Quick Info` to `False`. Check if that may help!

Comment: Macmade: Definitely not.

Comment: @Macmade, questions about software tools used by programmers (including IDE's) are explicitly mentioned in the FAQ as being on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the help tips from **CodeRush** which is a [IDE productivity tool](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) from DevExpress. You can disable it by going to your tools menu and select **DevExpres->UnLoad**

[image]

Doing this will not only disable the smart tips, but the whole CodeRush.

Personally, It is not annoying for me. This helps me to be more productive. In a single statment "***I love CodeRush to have in my VS environment***"

Comment: Will this remove DevExpress as well? Will it affect all users or just me (it's on our server)?

Comment: @Lindsay, Nope, it will just not load coderush, and just for your visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

The first of your images is a **CodeIssue** tip.

These can be toggled on and off via the first icon on the [**DXCore Visualize** toolbar](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/rorybecker/archive/2010/07/26/The-DXCore-Visualize-Toolbar.aspx)

The second item (the 'What happened' popup) was likely triggered because of a choice made when running VS after installing CodeRush for the first time.

It can be reversed through our options screen:

- Select **DevExpress \ Options**
- Locate the **Core \ Features** page.
- Uncheck the first option
- Click Ok

More detail regarding the 'What happened' popup can be found [in this blog post](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/rorybecker/archive/2010/08/25/coderush-notifications.aspx) on various CodeRush notifications.

Note: This post refers to version 10.1.5 of CodeRush. The latest version at the time of writing is 12.1.6.